# focusout event not being triggered on part of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, focusout

I want the focusout event to be triggered on input elements with class="date" and reside in tables with class='datatable', both for elements in the DOM and elements added dynamically. For dynamically added elements (using createElement and appendChild), the following code works successfully:

```
$('.datatable').on('focusout','tr td input', function(){
    if (this.class == 'date') {
        this.value = dateValid(this.value);
    }
});
```

However, for elements that are loaded into the DOM, the above code doesn't work. I also tried the code below, but it doesn't work either:

```
$('.date').focusout(dateValid(this.value));
```

The HTML for the input elements that are not triggering the focusout event:

```
<table class="datatable">
    <tr>
        <td>Prospective Effective Date</td>
        <td><input class="date" type="text" name="effectivedate"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Prospective Expiration Date</td>
        <td><input class="date" type="text" name="expirationdate"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm very new to JavaScript, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What errors show up in the console when you hit F12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is with the reserved keyword "class":

```
if (this.class == 'date') {
 //...
}
```

use `className`

```
if (this.className === 'date') {
 //...
}
```

if that doesn't fix the issue. you might be appending additional `table.datatable` elements instead of `tr` elements inside the existing table. you can solve that by binding the `focusout` to the `document`

```
$(document).on('focusout','input.date', function(){
 //...
});
```

Comment: Yes, when I changed "class" to "className" it worked, thanks!